# How can I use regexp to match ctx.url like ''/?id=xxx'' and "/" in koa?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, koa

When I type `/` in browser, the koa `ctx.url` info is `/`.
When I type `/?aaa=23322` in browser, the koa `ctx.url` info is still `/?aaa=23322`, How can I use regexp to match `ctx.url` like `/?id=xxx` and `/` in koa?

My code, when the guest access `/` and `/admin` , the app would redirect to `/login`, but when the guest access `/?aaa=aaa` , will bypass the 
auth condition.

```
if ((ctx.url === '/' || ctx.path.match(/^\/admin/)) && !ctx.session.userInfo) {
    // auth
    await ctx.redirect('/login');
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Have you taken a look into `ctx.request.querystring` ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved, use `ctx.path` not `ctx.url`